# Is MPAndroidchart compatible with android 8.0 (Oreo)?

Tags: mpandroidchart, android-8.0-oreo

I am planning to generate some graphs for my app using MPAndroidchart. I read in a couple of places on the web that MPAndroidchart is not compatible with android 8.0 (Oreo). Does it really go up to android 7.0? Not sure if I should believe this information or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide sources? I used/tested the library several times on android 8 devices/emulators and had no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with oreo I tested it on emulators. Everything is perfectly alright you can go with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess comments on youtube should not be taken very seriously sometimes.